# Connecting to database running on virtual server

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine

I would like to connect from local machine (either with SSMS or even better through my Access application) to a SQL Server Express database which I transferred to a virtual server in the cloud.

It is a Windows 2012 Server running as a VM. I can reach this server by RDP, but do not know how to connect to the database.

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- SSMS 2012
- on local machine: SSMS 2012, Access 2010

Thanks for replies maybe even with examples for a connection string.

Michael

Comment: Documentation is your friend: [Lesson 1: Connecting to the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You should also be able to `telnet server:1433` or `telnet 1.2.3.4:1433` to check/verify connectivity.

Comment: I was wrong,,  Remove the colon with telnet..  Ref.  https://ss64.com/nt/telnet.html and look at the example there.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Meanwhile I found a tutorial in youtube which solved my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZSCnWTnvHs